# how to round figure mysql row result

Tags: php, mysql, rounding

how to round figure mysql result value

```
$earnedbasic=$runrows['salary']/$runrows['days']*$runrows['countdaystotal'];
```

**example: salary divide by days multiply by workingdays**

```
150 salary
29 days
30 workingdays

150/29x30=155.17241
```

if result is like that
so i want round figure the value example now 155.17241 and i want like that 155.173 only
please help me to fix this issue

```
<?php



       while ($runrows = mysql_fetch_assoc($run))
       {

        //get data
       $workerid = $runrows['workerid'];
       $keywords = $runrows['keywords'];
       $salary =  $runrows['salary'];
       $days = $runrows['days'];
       $countdaystotal = $runrows['countdaystotal'];
       $earnedbasic=$runrows['salary']/$runrows['days']*$runrows['countdaystotal'];


 echo "<table class='sortable' border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
        echo "<tr> <th>ID</th> <th>Name</th><th>Basic</th><th>Days</th> <th>Earned Basic</th><th>Total Salary</th></tr>";


     echo "<tr width='50%' onmouseover=\"this.style.backgroundColor='#999999';\" onmouseout=\"this.style.backgroundColor='#d4e3e5';\"><td width='20%'><a href=\"detail.php?id=$id\" class=\"style1\">$workerid</a></td>
     <td width='20%'>$keywords</td>
    <td width='20%'>$salary</td>
     <td width='20%'>$countdaystotal</td>
     <td width='20%'>$earnedbasic</td></tr>";


echo "</table>";
       }

     }



    }


?>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: You do know you can just do the calculation on the database side? Perhaps post your query here.

Comment: this kind of code will not give you desired results. If it looks normal to you does not mean it cant be hacked. I would suggest using PDO instead of mysql functions. and for rounding see php.net/round

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<td width='20%'>".round($earnedbasic, 3)."</td>
```

or

```
$earnedbasic=round($runrows['salary']/$runrows['days']*$runrows['countdaystotal'],3);
```

Comment: i put like that  <td width='20%'>round($earnedbasic, 3)</td> but its not working

Comment: That should fix it - but the one you used would make more sense in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Erm... [`round($earnedbasic,3)`](http://php.net/round) should do it.

Comment: Wherever the hell you like.